# Program 'test.exe' failed to run: Access is denied vs code C error

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Txg.png)

```
Program 'test.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:91
+ ... cuments\arpit\" ; if ($?) { gcc test.c -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
+                                                                  ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:91
+ ... cuments\arpit\" ; if ($?) { gcc test.c -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
+                                                                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

this is the error i have been getting on my VS code .. i have installed the latest version of Min GW and also all the extention required .. i have not been able to find out the solution please help... P.S i am able to run C++ programs without any issues but not the C programs

Comment: make sure you save your files before compiling. My other guess would be an overly enthusiastic virus scanner

Comment: don't call your program `test`

Comment: @rioV8 what's wrong with calling a program test?

Comment: many OS have a command `test`

Comment: which MinGW version are you using? MinGW-w64 provides most recent versions, see for example the standalone version from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: Looks like VS code compiles the program into a file named `text`, but attempts to run `test.exe` ("test.exe failed..."). Check if VS code produces any executable binary and if so, under which name and - most importantly - in which directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same error just a few minutes ago, but I found the solution. It is because your Antivirus program 'erases?' the exe files so they can't run. If you are using Avast, you should turn off hardened mode (stopped working after I turned it on). This is the video where I found the solution. It works for me just fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMOjIjGYjcA

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30272499)